# I don´t want trigger to rollback

Tags: mysql, triggers

Sooo, I´m writing in MySQL a trigger to count how many attempts of an insert query happened (even failed attempts) but so far nothing.

If the insert is succesful, the variable 'attempts' increases its value by one. But when the insert query fails (because you tried to insert something ilogical) the trigger makes a rollback and 'attempts' doesn't increase.

How to avoid the rollback? Or how to outsmart it so 'attempts' will increase?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE myData (myValues INT);
SET attempts =0;

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER countingAttempts BEFORE INSERT ON myData FOR EACH ROW 
    SET @attempts = @attempts+1;
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO myData VALUES(10); /* It works, attempts becomes 1*/
INSERT INTO myData VALUES (X); /* The insert query fails because 'myValues' is INT and X is not an INT, attempts should become 2, but the trigger rollsback and attemps doesn´t change*/
```

Comment: can you show sample data (create table and insert) that demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Better? I'm not sure if I explained myself

Comment: do you mean something like `VALUES ("X")`?  `VALUES (X)` is just going to give an error because it has no idea what you mean by X

Comment: I'd recommend creating a log table with an ID and timestamp. Before calling the insert on myData, insert data into this log table. That way, you'll know how many attempts have been made to insert regardless of any database error or rollback.

Comment: I do mean  VALUES (X) . What I'm trying to do is increase @attempts   with or without  error

Comment: (1) `SET attempts =0;` and `SET @attempts = @attempts+1;` sets two different variables; (2) The error is detected during query analysing, the insertion have not started, there was no 2nd attempt, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67b1e2bbd498cdcab674f88c46f5726e ; (3) Use General Log (may be too expensive).

Comment: @zedfoxus That sounds great! But I never made a log table, any advise?

Comment: Yeah, do `create table insert_log (id int auto_increment primary key, inserted_at datetime default current_timestamp);` to create a log table. Before you do `INSERT INTO myData VALUES(10);`, do `insert into insert_log (id) values (default);`. Before you do `INSERT INTO myData VALUES (X);`, do `insert into insert_log (id) values (default);`. Then, you can do `select * from insert_log;` to see when insert statements were attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to count attempted inserts that result in errors due to bad data (presumably with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode enabled).

There is no "rollback", since no insert was actually done.  The trigger simply isn't executed by the point the error is detected.
(Though if you are inserting multiple rows, the trigger will be executed for initial correct rows before the erroneous one, so you will see the variable increased in that case.)

You could experiment with disabling STRICT_TRANS_TABLES and doing some validation in your trigger instead, but that's going to have an effect on all other tables and update statements too, so I wouldn't recommend it.

The other option I see is to not do inserts from the client, but instead call a stored procedure to do the insert; that gives you a chance to increment your counter in the stored procedure whether the insert works or not.

Comment: OHHHH!!! I thought the trigger was being executed before catching the error and then a rollback was undoing the changes (atomicity of transactions). I can't thank you enough

Comment: atomicity of transactions don't apply to variables; I don't think mysql has any mechanism that undoes variables changes